# How to use GCP speech-to-text api in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to use GCP speech-to-text api . I am newbie in this technology .

The main objective is to convert speech to text . Trying to convert speech to text  through plain JavaScript . I am facing badrequest error on api call. can anyone guide me ?

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      button {margin: 5px; padding: 10px 20px; background-color: #007bff; color: #fff; border: none; border-radius: 5px; cursor: pointer;}
      button:hover {background-color: #0056b3;}
      div { margin-top: 20px;}
   </style>

</head>
<body>
   <h3> Using the Media recorder API to record the audio in the web browser </h3>
   <div>
      <button id = "start"> Start Recording </button>
      <button id = "stop"> Stop Recording </button>
      <button id = "play"> Play Recorded Audio </button>
   </div> <br> 
   <div id = "output"> </div>
   <script>
      const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
      const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
      const playButton = document.getElementById('play');
      let output = document.getElementById('output');
      let audioRecorder;
      let audioChunks = [];

      async function sendAudioToGCP(blob) {
        const apiKey = '---';
        const url = `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${apiKey}`;
    
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('audio', blob);
    
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });
    
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
            }
    
            const data = await response.json();
            const transcript = data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
            return transcript;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending audio to GCP:', error);
            return null; 
        }
    }


      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
         .then(stream => {
         
            
            audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            
           
            audioRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', e => {
               audioChunks.push(e.data);
            });
            
            
            startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
               audioChunks = [];
               audioRecorder.start();
               output.innerHTML = 'Recording started! Speak now.';
            });
            
           
            stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
               audioRecorder.stop();
               output.innerHTML = 'Recording stopped! Click on the play button to play the recorded audio.';
            });
            
       
            playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
               const blobObj = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
               sendAudioToGCP(blobObj).then(transcript => {
                if (transcript !== null) {
                    
                    console.log('Transcript:', transcript);
                } else {
                    
                    console.log('Error sending audio to GCP');
                }
            });
               const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobObj);
               const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
               audio.play();
               output.innerHTML = 'Playing the recorded audio!';
            });
         }).catch(err => {
         
           
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
         });

         
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created API KEY for gcp project , please tell if I am missing any setup on gcp aswell

[image]

ps : also tell if it is possible using plain js , instead of using nodejs technology